# Leaflet map missing height in a content container in a full page Bootstrap template

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to show a Leaflet web map in the container of the content in a full page Bootstrap template.

I have well set up all css and js files required to run Bootstrap and Leaflet.

The style looks like:

```css
#col-sm-8 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#travelContent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="row content">
      <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
        <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 text-left">
        <h1>test</h1>
        <div id="travelContent">
          <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
        <div class="well">
          <p>ADS</p>
        </div>
        <div class="well">
          <p>ADS</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
    <p>Footer Text</p>
  </footer>

</body>
```

There was no map displayed on the page when previewed. The Developer Tool on Firefox indicated the `travelContent` and the `map` divs were with 0 height. I want the map to fill up the space for the parent containers which would fill up the browser.
[image]

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3 or 4? Looks like 3 for me.

Comment: The code is definitely Bootstrap 3 while the question is tagged with Bootstrap 4. Go figure...

Comment: Sorry I am new to Bootstrap. It should be Bootstrap 3.